# Языки программирования для разработки под Андроид

Tags: android, java

На каком языке еще можно разрабатывать для Андроид?.. Ява совсем не устраивает.

Comment: Ну ясно почему не устраивает ява... Джава бы точно устроила :)

Comment: А на Objective-C можно писать под Android? Или только под iOS?

Comment: На андройд точно нельзя

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На Javascript'е можно: [Разработка мобильных приложений на PhoneGap и jQuery Mobile](http://habrahabr.ru/post/118059/)

Answer (score 9):

По человечески под Android можно писать только под C/C++ и Java. Все остальное это костыли. Расшифровываю. Вариантов реализации других языков здесь 2:

1. Некая среда для скриптирования написанная на C/C++/Java - примеры SL4A, KiVy иже с ними.
2. Некий универсальный фреймворк, со своим скриптирующим языком, который генерирует исходные тексты в зависимости от выбранной платформы или же выдает HTML/JavaScript на браузер (PhoneGap).

В любом случае вы будете иметь дополнительную прослойку между осью и вами. Прослойка всегда имеет свои собственные баги, ограничения - не все фичи поддерживаются и проч. Как показывает практика на костылях можно написать только что-то простенькое, элементарное - костыли они и есть костыли.

Исключение составляет разве что Mono - платформа для разработки под C#. Фактически это полноценный .NET фреймворк способный работать под массой различных осей и ввиду этого заслуживает одобрения и похвалы. Единственный его минус - он платный.

В общем учите Java или С/С++

Comment: Для результата иногда костыли уместнее, чем пуристский "Тру" подход. Не будем разводить холивар про ассемблер : )

Comment: Конечно не будем :) - просто посчитаем количество приложений в маркете написанных на костылях

Comment: Совершенно согласен с Бармалеем: если писать серьезные, и тем более, коммерческие, приложения, то только указанные им языки. Остальные для небольших домашних проектов.

Answer (score 4):

Можно на С++: [Как написать программу на C++ для Android. Без Java.](http://www.codeatcpp.com/2012/01/c-android-4-java.html)

Answer (score 3):

Python, при помощи фреймворка [Kivy](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/)

Answer (score 3):

[Lua](http://www.lua.org/) на [Corona SDK](http://www.coronalabs.com/) — сразу под iPhone и под Андроид будете девелопить. О, сегодня как раз [пост на Хабре про Lua](http://habrahabr.ru/post/149857/), немного в другом контексте.

Answer (score 2):

Один из перспективных вариантов - это разработка мобильных приложений на C# при помощи [Mono for Android и Monotouch](http://xamarin.com/).

Плюсы:

- Можно писать кроссплатформенные библиотеки, что сильно облегчит портирование приложения на iPhone.
- Разработка на полноценном C# со всеми вытекающими от сюда плюсами.
- Компиляция приложений в нативный код.

Минусы:

- Цена. Персональная лицензия стоит $400 за платформу.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript, HTML5 и CSS3 при помощи PhoneGap позволит писать приложения почти под все мобильные платформы.

Answer (score 2):

С помощью [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) можно программировать на  Python, Perl, JRuby, Lua, BeanShell, JavaScript, Tcl и shell. Планируется добавление других скриптовых языков.